# error generate-specs.sh No such file or directory

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to build react native app for IOS

when i tried to build im getting issue saying

Showing Recent Messages
bash: /Users/admin/Documents/project/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: No such file or directory

Showing Recent Messages
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
"react-native": "0.72.4",

even i have tried the https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32157

Still same issue says No such file or directory